# Cloud Foundry cli commands failing "Error performing request: lame referral"

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I have single VM cloud foundry setup on azure machine(4cores, 28GB RAM).
Initially the cf cli commands work fine. I am able to login(cf login) to cf and push(cf push) applications and see the hosted apps(cf apps) too.

```
azure-user@dsapi-boshvm:~$ cf apps

Getting apps in org default_organization / space azure as admin...

OK

name    requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls
myapp   started           3/3         128M     256M   myapp.example.com
```

After sometime the same command fails

```
azure-user@dsapi-boshvm:~$ cf apps
Getting apps in org default_organization / space azure as admin...

FAILED

Error performing request: Get https://api.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io/v2/spaces/80d34326-cffc-4b62-98b6-ddd1c087ca59/summary: dial tcp: lookup api.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx: lame referral

TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
```

Later the cf cli commands dont respond at all.

```
azure-user@dsapi-boshvm:~$ cf apps

Getting apps in org default_organization / space azure as admin...
```

No Response for the above command.

Not sure if the issue is happening because of machine hardware specifications.

Answer (score 0):

`xip.io` was in my experience (and many others) not a very stable DNS service.
At some point (around Oct 2015, CF v219), domain `bosh-lite.com` was set up to replace use of xip.io for bosh-lite.
I don't know how your CF has been installed and configured, but it might be as easy as doing a `cf api api.bosh-lite.com` (possibly with the `--skip-ssl-validation` flag if you cannot copy your API endpoint's cert to your truststore) and use that as your endpoint instead.
(bosh-lite.com and all its subdomains resolve to 10.244.0.34).